# How To Scrape A TableIn Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I just started with Python. Trying to scrape tables from...
http://www.dramexchange.com/

But haven't been successful yet.

```
import requests, bs4
r = requests.get('http://www.dramexchange.com/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml') 
for table in contents.find_all(class_='tb_NationalDramSpotPrice'):
title = table.find(class_='title').text
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    _, Item, Daily High, Daily Low. Session High. Session Low. Session Average, Session Change = [td for td in tr.stripped_strings]
    print(Item, Daily High, Daily Low. Session High. Session Low. Session Average, Session Change)
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Answer (score 0):

To start it looks like you aren't actually referencing the correct variable in your first iterator:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml') 
for table in contents.find_all(class_='tb_NationalDramSpotPrice'):
```

Notice you are calling `find_all()` on the variable `contents`, not on `soup` as declared before.

I went the extra step to actually pull in the site you're trying to scrape and it actually doesn't contain a class of 'tb_NationalDramSpotPrice', but an *id* of that name. That would add additional problems.